# How to add MUI DataGrid Edit/delete Button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I am having a hard time adding custom buttons per row in the DataGrid component.

This is my code:

```
const columns = [
    { field: 'model_id', headerName: 'ID', width: 70, sortable: false },
    { field: 'model_code', headerName: 'Model Code', width: 130 },
    { field: 'model_description', headerName: 'Description', width: 400 },
    { field: 'actions', headerName: 'Actions', width: 400 }
];
```

DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid
rows={models}
columns={columns}
getRowId={(row) => row.model_id}
pageSize={5}
rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
checkboxSelection />
```

What I want per row:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `renderCell` function in column definition array like this:

```
const onButtonClick = (e, row) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    //do whatever you want with the row
};

const columns = [
    { field: 'model_id', headerName: 'ID', width: 70, sortable: false },
    { field: 'model_code', headerName: 'Model Code', width: 130 },
    { field: 'model_description', headerName: 'Description', width: 400 },
    { field: 'actions', headerName: 'Actions', width: 400, renderCell: (params) => {
        return (
          <Button
            onClick={(e) => onButtonClick(e, params.row)}
            variant="contained"
          >
            Delete
          </Button>
        );
      } }
];
```

You can take a look at [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mui-datagrid-button) for a live working example of this solution.

Comment: Thank you. Just wanna ask why it is not on the documentation on DataGrid API? https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/

Comment: Because this is not a direct prop to be passed to DataGrid. We pass `renderCell` inside of an array through `columns` prop. This page has the definition of the api of column definitions: https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/grid-col-def/